# Include taking long time to execute

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Includes taking long time to execute, I have tried to divide in chunks but its still time taking with large records.

```
      var logbookEntriesFromDbQuery = ctx.LogbookEntries
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(le => le.PatientDetail)
            .Include(le => le.AlternateSupervisor)
            .Include(le => le.Hospital)
            .Include(le => le.Logbook.LogbookType.Specialty)
            .Include(le => le.Logbook.LogbookType.Fields)
            .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryProcedures.Select(lep => lep.Procedure.ProcedureLogbookTypes.Select(plt => plt.Categories)))
            .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryProcedures.Select(lep =>
                lep.LogbookEntryProcedureFields.Select(lepf => lepf.ProcedureField).Select(pf => pf.ProcedureProcedureFields)))
            .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryProcedures.Select(lep =>
                lep.LogbookEntryProcedureFields.Select(lepf => lepf.ProcedureField)
                    .Select(pf => pf.ProcedureLogbookTypeProcedureFields)))
            .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryDiagnoses.Select(led => led.Diagnosis.DiagnosisLogbookTypes))
            .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryDiagnoses.Select(led =>
                led.LogbookEntryDiagnosisProcedureFields.Select(ledpf => ledpf.ProcedureField)
                    .Select(pf => pf.DiagnosisProcedureFields)))
            .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryDiagnoses.Select(led =>
                led.LogbookEntryDiagnosisProcedureFields.Select(ledpf => ledpf.ProcedureField)
                    .Select(pf => pf.DiagnosisLogbookTypeProcedureFields)))
            .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryProcedures.Select(lep => lep.LogbookEntryProcedureComplications))
            .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryStatus)
            .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryComments)
            .Where(le => le.LogbookId == logbookId)
            .Where(le => le.LogbookEntryDate > thirtyDaysAgo);
```

Comment: Hi Toshee,
welcome to the site.  To proceed, we are going to need more information.  Where are you pulling the data from (is it a database or something else)?  What is the question you would like answered?

Comment: Hi I am pulling data from sql database.And due to many includes its taking very long time to return records.

Comment: Try turning off `AsNoTracking` and loading each entity separately.  The change tracker will fix up the navigation properties.  Or just use Lazy Loading.

Comment: How long is it taking? How long do you want it to take? What SQL is being submitted to the database?

Comment: Try to construct the query by yourself, and run it in the database, what is the performance? And then you could try linq query to map the sql query in the DbContext.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data you are loading?  Are you populating a UI list? If so, what fields from what entities are being displayed in the list?

Answer (score 1):

it is because having several Includes are generating several JOINS in the query, and joins usually are a very time-consuming processes. If you really need to load all that information (to show it in a table for example) a good option would be to create a View in your db, if you don't need to show all the info at once you can take out the Includes and get each field separately only when you need to use it, hope this helps you

Answer (score -1):

I have tried below but still taking too long.

```
        var logbookEntriesFromDb = await ctx.LogbookEntries
            .Include(le => le.PatientDetail)
            .Include(le => le.AlternateSupervisor)
            .Where(le => le.LogbookId == logbookId)
            .Where(le => le.LogbookEntryDate > thirtyDaysAgo)
            .ToListAsync();

        logbookEntriesFromDb = await ctx.LogbookEntries
         .Include(le => le.Hospital)
         .Include(le => le.Logbook.LogbookType.Specialty)
         .Where(le => le.LogbookId == logbookId)
         .Where(le => le.LogbookEntryDate > thirtyDaysAgo)
         .ToListAsync();

        logbookEntriesFromDb = await ctx.LogbookEntries
         .Include(le => le.Logbook.LogbookType.Fields)
         .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryProcedures.Select(lep => lep.Procedure.ProcedureLogbookTypes.Select(plt => plt.Categories)))
         .Where(le => le.LogbookId == logbookId)
         .Where(le => le.LogbookEntryDate > thirtyDaysAgo)
         .ToListAsync();

        logbookEntriesFromDb = await ctx.LogbookEntries
         .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryProcedures.Select(lep =>
             lep.LogbookEntryProcedureFields.Select(lepf => lepf.ProcedureField).Select(pf => pf.ProcedureProcedureFields)))
         .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryProcedures.Select(lep =>
             lep.LogbookEntryProcedureFields.Select(lepf => lepf.ProcedureField)
                 .Select(pf => pf.ProcedureLogbookTypeProcedureFields)))
         .Where(le => le.LogbookId == logbookId)
         .Where(le => le.LogbookEntryDate > thirtyDaysAgo)
         .ToListAsync();

        logbookEntriesFromDb = await ctx.LogbookEntries
          .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryDiagnoses.Select(led => led.Diagnosis.DiagnosisLogbookTypes))
          .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryDiagnoses.Select(led =>
              led.LogbookEntryDiagnosisProcedureFields.Select(ledpf => ledpf.ProcedureField)
                  .Select(pf => pf.DiagnosisProcedureFields)))
          .Where(le => le.LogbookId == logbookId)
          .Where(le => le.LogbookEntryDate > thirtyDaysAgo)
          .ToListAsync();

        logbookEntriesFromDb = await ctx.LogbookEntries
          .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryDiagnoses.Select(led =>
              led.LogbookEntryDiagnosisProcedureFields.Select(ledpf => ledpf.ProcedureField)
                  .Select(pf => pf.DiagnosisLogbookTypeProcedureFields)))
          .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryProcedures.Select(lep => 
        lep.LogbookEntryProcedureComplications))
          .Where(le => le.LogbookId == logbookId)
          .Where(le => le.LogbookEntryDate > thirtyDaysAgo)
          .ToListAsync();

        logbookEntriesFromDb = await ctx.LogbookEntries
            .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryStatus)
            .Include(le => le.LogbookEntryComments)
            .Where(le => le.LogbookId == logbookId)
            .Where(le => le.LogbookEntryDate > thirtyDaysAgo)
            .ToListAsync();
```